# Excel displays duplicate calendar picker control (Macros VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, datepicker, activex

I've created a macros-enabled Excel file where, when clicking into a specific cell, a pop-up calendar appears. It is an ActiveX control (Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0 (SP4)). From time to time the calendar control appears next to the clicked cell and is unclickable and a duplicate control appears in the left top corner of the worksheet and this one is clickable.

[image: duplicate controls appear]

I would like it to appear just next to the clicked cell. What could be wrong?

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Sheet1.startPicker
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E2:E10000")) Is Nothing Then
            .Visible = True
            .Top = Target.Top
            .Right = Target.Offset(0, 1).Right
        Else
            .Visible = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub startPicker_Change()
    ActiveCell.Value = Me.startPicker.Value
End Sub
```

When I click on the date picker control in Design Mode, then the name is set to startpicker and in the formula bar it says "=EMBED("MSComCtl2.DTPicker.1";"")"

Comment: You probably actually have 2 with the same name?  If you don't think so, I'd be interested to take a look at the actual file if you wanted to share it...  it's indeed a little strange that one of them is on top of the row/column headings.

Comment: Excel always had some strange behavior with ActiveX, I won't wonder if this is just a bug of the ActiveX at all.

Comment: And are you sure there is a `.Right` parameter for a range and the picker at all? I cannot find only `.Left` and `.Top`, I'm pretty sure there is no `.Right`. Is there any `On Error Resume Next` in your code? If so remove it! This will only suppress errors so you can't see them but they still occur. Instead of setting the right try setting the left `.Left = Target.Left + Target.Width`

Comment: Thank you, PEH! You are right about the fact that there is no ".Right" and the ".Left = Target.Left + Target.Width" is a good replacement for it. However, unfortunately, it has not fixed the duplicate picker problem.

ashleedawg, I have no problem sharing my code, but what would be the best way? Just putting it in the comment would make it unviewable...

Comment: @ashleedawg since we talk about ActiveX controls there is no possibility to have 2 controls with the same name. It would not let you name the second if there is already one with that name.

Comment: @ositra can you figure out if there is a pattern when this happens and when not? I mean you say it happens "from time to time", but does this always happen on the same cell? Or does it sometimes work on a cell and sometimes on that same cell it doesn't? Can you probably share the full code of that sub? You can [edit] your original question to add code in a formatted way.

Comment: Looking at this article, it seems that it truly is an ActiveX problem, but I haven't found a 100% confirmation on this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_2010/datepicker-doesnt-lookact-the-same-after-closing/8657c238-f0eb-40dd-b9e0-cb37289dfee6

Comment: @ositra That is why I recommend to stay away from ActiveX at all whenever possible. They often have strange effects on Excel and sometimes cause more issues than they solve. You might have a look if you can update Office and if this might solve your issue.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, I added the code to the original post. Not much there.

Answer (score 0):

Just now I tried changing the Checkbox (in the Calendar Properties) to True. Then when I went back, the duplicate one was gone. Changed it back to False and it didn't return.

Comment: I assume this is a solution. I removed the first part of your solution as it was completely redundant.

Comment: I've seen several posts around the web about this problem, and no one seems to have a real solution. It seems to work fine for most people, so maybe we're just unlucky. Anyway, I tried turning the checkbox property on and off, saving between settings, and the control still pops up to the upper left for me.

Comment: I just found this discussion that points out that scrolling down and back up causes the "floating" calendar control to go away. Also, Freeze Top Row or Freeze Panes (if you include a row) makes it go away (you see it for a second when opening but it goes away immediately). If you freeze the first column, the floater stays until you scroll down and up. [Discussion](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_o365b/excel-date-picker-buggy-unreliable-does-not-copy/cc02548a-5a8f-4ffc-af83-220cd8f25d54?auth=1)